# Grouping multiple buttons with absolute positioning in a layout

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, qgroupbox

Is it possible to group buttons that are arbitrarily positionned with PyQt ?

There is the context :
I would like to code a visual programm to control a research system with specific geometry, through Python.
I expect this kind of result :

[image: expected program]

In this program, the buttons of "buttons group 3" are positionned is a specific geometry that does not fit in a grid. Those buttons are clickable and a click on them change their color.
I would like those buttons to be grouped together, in something like a layout, because it seems to be that it is coherent in order to change positions and sizes of layouts and window if needed.

I'm coding that with PYQT5,... but I cannot figure in PyQt5 how to code this group of buttons with specific geometry ?

Is it possible to group buttons that are arbitrarily positionned with PyQt ?

Thanks in advance for your advice, I feel I'm missing something in PyQt concept.

Comment: Off the top of my head: one idea would be to use a 3 rows x 5 columns `QGridLayout` and use mock / invisible / spacer widgets in between your actual buttons (so that e.g. row 1 is composed of: < spacer | A3 | spacer | B3 | spacer >). Another idea would be to increase the left margin of buttons `A3` and `F3`, and the right margin of buttons `B3` and `G3`, although I feel like this will be harder to look great once the window is resized.

Comment: **If** there is no vertical overlapping, using a grid could be a solution, but due to the required spanning, at least 6 or 9 columns might be necessary: C3 will use column 0 and 1, A3/F3 column 1 and 2 (or 1 to 3), D3 column 2 and 3 (or 3 to 5), etc. The image you show, though, seem to have a slight overlapping, which would make it a bit difficult, so *maybe* 5 rows might be necessary too, with a concept similar to the above. The only (and possibly better) alternative is to manually set geometries in the `resizeEvent` of the container, without any QLayout.